# VBA copy and paste pivot values and format

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I try to copy and paste a pivot table, but I want to keep values and format.

```
Sub PivotTablePaste()

    Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
    pt.TableRange2.Copy

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1")

        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Comment: No it just bring the numbers no color no bold of totals nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this works **only** with `PivotTable.TableRange1`
(which is the main range of the pivottable without the filters i. e. the `PageFields` above it)
and **not** with the full `PivotTable.TableRange2`.

If your pivottable has pagefields also, then you have to copy that range above the pivottable additionally cell-by-cell.

```
Sub PivotTablePaste()
    Dim SourcePivottable As PivotTable
    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set SourcePivottable = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
    Set DestinationRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1")

    ' Copy TableRange1
    SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Copy
    With DestinationRange.Offset( _
      SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Row - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Row, 0)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With

    ' Copy everything above TableRange1 cell-by-cell
    For Each aCell In SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Cells
        If Not Intersect(aCell, SourcePivottable.TableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit For
        aCell.Copy
        With DestinationRange.Offset( _
          aCell.Row - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Row, _
          aCell.Column - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Column)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With
    Next aCell

End Sub
```