# I can't paste pivot table formats to another page

Tags: vba, format, pivot-table, copy-paste

Trying to copy and paste a Pivot Table on Excel from one page to the other.
Code works but it does not paste the formats.

```
Sub TestPivotPaste()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Worksheets(8)
Set copyrange = sh.Range("A1:Z50")
Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(9)


copyrange.Copy
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

End Sub
```

I tried to do it on the same page

```
Sub TestPivotPaste()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Worksheets(8)
Set copyrange = sh.Range("A1:Z50")
copyrange.Copy
sh.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
sh.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
sh.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
End Sub
```

It still gets copied without formats and I get
Run-time error 1004: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed and the guilty line is

```
sh.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

I can't figure out where the problem is by looking at similar answer on this website

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and rerun. Do you get an error message?

Comment: @BigBen Yes I get run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range

Comment: On what line do you get that error? Please [edit] your question with the error description and the line that throws it, thanks!

Comment: If you add a new workbook, it probably won't have a sheet named with the same name as the original `sh`, right?

Comment: ^ though this is a side issue and not related to the Pivot Table formatting.

Comment: @BigBen
I removed that line and it is throwing another error that could be possibly related to it.
Run time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set
and it refers to this line of code:
```Set CopiedRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column))

Comment: It sounds like the `Find` was unsuccessful and `lastcell` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Well if last cell is Nothing then I should get nothing pasted on the new page. On the other hand I get exactly the range I want. The only thing missing is the Pivot Table format.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56602988/10908769) how to copy a pivot table with formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA copy and paste pivot values and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56596120/vba-copy-and-paste-pivot-values-and-format)

Comment: Thank you Asger.
My problem is that I have multiple pivot tables on each page and other pages that I need to copy to a new file only contains regular data.
Does it mean I can't use the same copy and paste routine for the regular data and the pivot tables?
Also with tabs with multiple pivot tables I have to copy and paste them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the whole table range as below (you might need to change the range the pivot table belongs to):

```
Sub TestPivotPaste()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Worksheets(8)
Set pt = sh.Range("A3").PivotTable
Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(9)
Set copyrange = pt.TableRange1

copyrange.Copy
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
sh1.Range("B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

End Sub
```

Comment: Using Pivot Table object is a solution I already explored, but the funny thing is that if I use TableRange2 (as I need to copy and paste the filters of the pivot) it does not paste the formats. It only works with TableRange1.
I can use the Pivot Table object only if I can paste the filters

Comment: So what you are trying to do is just to copy the pivot table with all its functionalities and formatting?

Comment: I do not want the functionalities, only values and formats. If I am not able to copy an entire page with the values and the formatting then, the only possibility that I have is to copy and paste the values and the formatting of all the pivot tables in the sheet.