# VBA to copy Pivot Table Data into another sheet + change headers

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to copy the data in plain format into another sheet, and do further transformation on it.

While I can create the Pivot Table, but whenever I try to copy it into another sheet, the new sheet is empty. Wondering if any experts can point me to where I'm doing this wrongly. Below are my codes for reference:

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim CSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'*****************************************************
'  Declare variables
'*****************************************************
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Pivot_Table").Delete
Worksheets("Cleaned_Data").Delete
Worksheets("RAW_DATA").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot_Table"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot_Table")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("RAW_DATA")

'*****************************************************
'  Define data range for pivot
'*****************************************************

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PivotRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'*****************************************************
'  Create pivot cache
'*****************************************************
Set PivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="UserPivotTable")

'*****************************************************
'  Insert blank pivot
'*****************************************************
Set PTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="UserPivotTable")

'*****************************************************
'  Insert row fields
'*****************************************************
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("UserPivotTable").PivotFields("userid")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

'*****************************************************
'  Insert data field
'*****************************************************
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("UserPivotTable").PivotFields("QTY")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    '.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    '.Name = "Revenue "
End With

'*****************************************************
'  Copy data into another sheet for cleaning
'*****************************************************
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Cleaned_Data"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set CSheet = Worksheets("Cleaned_Data")

PTable.TableRange2.Copy
CSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Also with that, how should I customize the headers once I have copied the data into the new sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consistency, add the missing variables to your dim section:

```
Dim pivotRange As Range
Dim pivotCache As pivotCache
```

And change your second last line, the copy line to:

```
PSheet.PivotTables("UserPivotTable").TableRange2.Copy
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work but why can't i use the PTable as an reference object to copy instead?

Comment: I have this horrible feeling that although I remember the documents saying that a pivottable is returned from a createPivotTable command, nothing actually is - so your pTable variable remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code, the you'll see, that `PivotCache` is `Nothing`.

Your code row `Set PivotCache =` is just too long.
As you only need the reference to a new `PivotCache` there, use this:

```
Set PivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotRange)
```

Further hints:
You should not use VBA-internal names as variable names.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56602988/10908769) concerning further formatting.

Comment: Be aware that the other answer and his "horrible feeling" is misleading. An `Option Explicit` above each module and a `Dim` for every variable is good practice, but defining a reference for the pivottable also. You should of course still use your reference `pTable` to address your newly generated pivottable (instead of `PSheet.PivotTables("UserPivotTable")`). Just shorten the a. m. code line and everything works.